# MultiTouch - Why only four fingers at most

Tags: java, android

I've tried implementing a multitouch program to test and understand how android works. I've tried the following code, but when I run it, only four out of ten possible IDs are being recognised on the screen, the other lines are just the default values I've set.

Here's the code:-

```
package com.example.chester;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

@TargetApi(8)
 public class MultiTouchTest extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
TextView textView;
float[] x = new float[10];
float[] y = new float[10];
boolean[] touched = new boolean[10];
int[] id = new int[10];

private void updateTextView() {
    builder.setLength(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        builder.append(touched[i]);
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(id[i]);
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(x[i]);
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(y[i]);
        builder.append("\n");
    }
    textView.setText(builder.toString());

}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Touch and drag (multiple fingers supported)!");
    textView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(textView);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        id[i] = -1;
    }
    updateTextView();
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i >= pointerCount) {
            touched[i] = false;
            id[i] = -1;
            continue;
        }
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                && i != pointerIndex) {
            continue;
        }
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(i);
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            touched[i] = true;
            id[i] = pointerId;
            x[i] = (int) event.getX(i);
            y[i] = (int) event.getY(i);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            touched[i] = false;
            id[i] = -1;
            x[i] = (int) event.getX(i);
            y[i] = (int) event.getY(i);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touched[i] = true;
            id[i] = pointerId;
            x[i] = (int) event.getX(i);
            y[i] = (int) event.getY(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    updateTextView();
    return true;
}
```

}

**EDIT:  I'm using a HTC Sensation with android 4.0.3**

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: HTC Sensation with android 4.0.3

Comment: Yeah as I thought, seems to be device limitation: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1258007

Comment: @KubaSpatny One of the most expensive phones 2 years ago, and it's already outdated! Thanks for taking the time to help

Answer (score 3):

The amount of touches you can have is device specific (depends on how they made the device and parts used), whereas android (as mobile os) supports up to 10.